# HSQLDB AS keyword is being ignored

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I'm not having any luck with Google or SO searches, so here goes.

I have the following SQL statement that I'm trying to run against HSQLDB 2.3.0.

```
select
tr.id as training_request_id,
s.id as student_id,
s.first_name as student_first_name,
s.last_name as student_last_name,
s.title as student_title,
c.id as customer_id,
c.name as customer_name,
trs.status
from training_request tr
left outer join student s on tr.student_id = s.id
left outer join customer c on tr.customer_id = c.id
left outer join training_request_status trs on tr.id = trs.training_request_id
where tr.slot_id is not null
order by tr.id, trs.date_entered DESC
```

When it comes back, the colums are:
ID, ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TITLE, ID, NAME, STATUS

Why isn't the AS keyword having any effect?

UPDATE:  Here's a screenshot from SQuirreL.  Quoting the student_id column has no effect.
[image]

Comment: Works for me. Which tool do you use to "see" the column names? Or how do you retrieve them in your code?

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but what if you put quotes around your column names?

Comment: Both SQuirreL and our custom ORM layer behave the same way.

Comment: Apparently Squirrel (and your custom ORM layer) only uses `getColumnName()` not `getColumnAlias()` to obtain the information from `ResultSetMetaData`

Comment: I like SQuirreL ok ... but it does have some idiosyncratic behaviors.  I am especially not fond of the way it lists only the first 200 rows of a result set or table without really telling you that it is showing only those.  In order to see unseen rows, you must use a filter.

Comment: @scottb, what do you mean?  There's a limit rows check box at the top right corner of the editing window.  On queries that were affected by the limit, it clearly displays "Limited to 100 rows;" with the number in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

There's a connection property called "get_column_name".  Set it to false.  The default is true.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/enrolments;get_column_name=false

Comment: Why did this need to be edited?  I know that's the example from HSQLDB's page, but wasn't the answer specific enough already?